# How to create an array in TI-89 Titanium calculator?

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I tried many different ways, but TI always gives me errors:

```
Invalid in a function or current experession
```

I tried

```
{0, 0, 0, 0}->A
```

and

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]->A
```

Both ways did not work. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the arrow from pressing the STO button, or literally typing in ->?

Comment: @Zach L: I used STO, not ->. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it solved:

```
Local lst
newList( n )->lst
```

We have to explicitly declare `lst` as local variable, and create a new list of `n` element with `newList()` function.